# Toggle effect using i tag instead of the background property for a dropdown button

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, font-awesome

I am interested in a dropdown which does not require JS. I've found some sources online and succeeded with that. However, I would like to alter the images that I am using as dropdown "buttons" by i tags (or any better suggestion) so I can use font-awesome/line-awesome classes instead (getting the .svg requires paid licence as far as I know).

I don't know what to do with the ***input:checked ~ label*** to change to the close icon if opting for

```html
<label for="dropOptsPost"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></label>
```

```css
.dropdown label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(img/closed.png) no-repeat left center;
  padding: 3rem 0 3rem 8rem;
}

/* Toggle effect */
input:checked ~ label {
  background: url(img/open.png) no-repeat left center;
}

input:checked ~ .dropdown-content {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown drop-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="dropdownMenu">
      <label for="dropdownMenu"></label>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#" title="">Option 1</a>
        <a href="#" title="">Option 2</a>
        <a href="#" title="">Option 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**
See my solution below in a similar example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.toggle-icon').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-times active');
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggle-icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-content.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle"><a href="javascript:void"><i class="toggle-icon fas fa-cogs"></i></a></div>
    <div class="toggle-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```